# how to use map in react to create multiple component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this array that has this structure please check the code down below , my end results should look like the following :

- veg
- apple
- carrot

---

- meat
- chicken
- steak

my current results are

apple
carrot
chicken
steak

since I cannot structure the array other wise and don't want to go in to deep nesting or even nest loops which I doubt it will work in react any idea how to achieve the previous results using map , where I map through group only once to create the group name and to then add the items related to that group inside that group?, food for thought : could conditional rendering be also leveraged here ?
I was able to only get either the group multiple times or the items only..

```js
const arr = {
  itmes: [
    { id: 1, group: "veg", item: "apple" },
    { id: 2, group: "veg", item: "carrot" },
    { id: 3, group: "meat", item: "chicken" },
    { id: 4, group: "meat", item: "steak" }
  ]
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {arr["itmes"].map(
        (item) => item.group
        //item.item
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Codesanadbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-stallman-xquie?file=/index.js)

Comment: Just do `(item) => i<li>{tem.group}</li>` See [Rendering multiple components](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components) for explanation

Comment: still this doesn't solve the issue of the array structure that I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the items first and render the grouped ones

```
const groupItems = items =>
  items.reduce((groupedItems, item) => {
    if (!groupedItems[item.group]) {
      groupedItems[item.group] = []
    }

    groupedItems[item.group].push(item)

    return groupedItems
  }, {})

const items = Object.entries(groupItems(arr.items)).map(
  ([groupName, items]) => (
    <React.Fragment>
      <li>{groupName}</li>
      {items.map(item => (
        <li>{item.item}</li>
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
)
```

[image: Edit vibrant-sky-jwrmf]

Answer (score 2):

Im very new to javascript, but like [hgb123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6655160/hgb123)'s answer, something like this inside a render or return block:

```
<div className="myClass">
  {myList.map((eachItemInList) => (
    <ReactComponent certainProp={eachItemInList} />
   ))}
</div>
```

works perfectly for a list like this one:

```
const myList = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6']
```

hope this helped someone!

Answer (score 1):

##### Option 1

First, make sure your array is sorted by Group:

```
const sorted = arr["itmes"]
    .sort((a, b) => (a.group || '').localeCompare(b.group));
```

Then you can render and conditionally add another heading element whenever the group name changes:

```
<ul>
    {data.map((d, id) => (
        <>
            ((id > 0 || d.group !== data[id - 1].group) ? <li key={`${id}-h`}><b>{d.group}</b></li> : undefined)
            <li key={`${id}-v`}>{d.item}</li>
        </>
    ))}
</ul>
```

##### Extra: Custom group sorting

If you need to custom sort the array according to another array:

```
const sortLtu = ['veg', 'apple', 'meat'];
data.sort((a, b) => sortLtu.indexOf(a.group) - sortLtu.indexOf(b.group));
```

##### Option 2: Util function

If you end u doing this often you may create a util function:

```
Array.prototype.groupBy = function(cb) {
    const groups = [];
    this.forEach((d, id, arr) => {
        const g = cb(d, id, arr);
        let group = groups.find(_g => _g.group === g);
        if (!group) {
            group = { group: g, items: [] };
            groups.push(group);
        }
        group.items.push(d);
    })
    return groups;
}
```

And then use it like

```
{data.groupBy(i => i.group).map((bundle, ix) => (
    <div key={ix}>
        <b>{bundle.group}</b>
        <ul>
            {bundle.items.map((item, ix) => <li key={ix}>{item.item}</li>)}
        </ul>
    </div>
))}
```